# How to change element's background-color with animation in click function?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, click, background-color

Is it possible to animate a background color change in a click function? I saw many examples with mouseover/hover functions but none with a click function. Only without animation following line works:

```
$('#element').css({ backgroundColor: "#99cc00" });
```

I tried to add an animation effect with:

```
$('#element').animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffffff' }, 2000);
```

and

```
$('#element').css({ backgroundColor: "#99cc00" }).animate({}, 2500);
```

but without an effect. Please have a look at my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dna6B/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include `JqueryUI` In project.

```
$('#element').animate({backgroundColor:'#99cc00'}, 2500);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dna6B/2/)**

Comment: Thx! It needs the JqueryUI library of course. That's it! Now it works!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using JQuery UI.

```
$('#element').click(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor:'#99cc00'}, 2500);
});
```

Update version of your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dna6B/1/)

Comment: Yeah thx, just found some code snippets and didn't know that the UI library is needed.

Answer (score 1):

to animate the background color you need to use jqueryUI

Lets say your current #element background is #000000

then doing this

```
$('#element').click(function() {
    $('#element').animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffffff' }, 2000);
});
```

will change animate the background from black to white in 2 seconds.

http://api.jqueryui.com/color-animation/

So you would need to include this in your head html, along with the regular jquery

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
```

Comment: Thx! It was written in the documentation: "Note: The jQuery UI project extends the .animate() method by allowing some non-numeric styles such as colors to be animated." but I didn't see it. *facepalm*